# socket.io.js 404 error not found in heroku app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, socket.io, http-status-code-404

This is a real time chat application developed using nodejs , socket.io and the messages are saved in mongo database with a specific url in the mongo database website.
i downloaded the demo file for nodejs from heroku and it is called node-js-getting-started and changed in the javascript , css and view file to match the application but when i push it and open console i get this : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) socket.io.js.

Index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var client = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url ="mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds153752.mlab.com:53752/chatapp";

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
   response.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err)throw err;
    client.on('connection', function(socket){
        var col = db.collection('messages'),
            sendStatus = function(s){
                socket.emit('status',s);
            };
        //emit all messages
        col.find().limit(200).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err,res){
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit('output',res);
        });

        // wait for input
        socket.on('input',function(data){
            var name = data.name,
            message = data.message,
            whitespacePattern = /^\s*$/;

          if(whitespacePattern.test(name)||whitespacePattern.test(message)){
             sendStatus('Name and Message is Required.');
          }else{
             col.insert({name:name,message:message},function(){
                //emit latest message to all clients
                client.emit('output',[data]);
                sendStatus({
                    message : "Message Sent",
                    clear : true
                });

             });    
         }

      });

 });

});
```

Index.ejs : (view)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Chat App </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
  
</head>
<body>

  <div class="chat">
    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <div class="chat-messages" style="">

    </div>
    <textarea placeholder="Type Your Message"></textarea>
    <div class="chat-status">Status : <span name="st" id ="st">Idle</span></div>
  </div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function(){
      var getNode = function(s){
        return document.querySelector(s);
      },

      textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
      messages = getNode('.chat-messages'),
      chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),
      status = getNode('.chat-status span'),

      statusDefault = status.textContent,
      setStatus = function(s){
        
        status.textContent = s;
        
        if(s !== statusDefault){
          var delay = setTimeout(function(){
            setStatus(statusDefault);
            clearInterval(delay);
          },3000);
        }


      };
      

      try{
        var socket = io.connect('https://evening-springs-70834.herokuapp.com');
      }catch(e){

      }
      if(socket !== undefined){

        //listen for output

        socket.on('output',function(data){
          if(data.length){
            for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++){
              var message = document.createElement('div');
              message.setAttribute('class','chat-message');
              message.textContent = data[x].name + ' : ' + data[x].message;
              message.style.marginBottom = 10 + 'px';
              messages.insertBefore(message,messages.firstChild);
              messages.appendChild(message);
              messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
            }
          }
        });
 
        //listen for status
        socket.on('status',function(data){
          setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);
          if(data.clear === true){
            textarea.value = '';
          } 
        });

        textarea.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
          var text = this,
            name = chatName.value;
          
          if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
            socket.emit('input',{
              name : name,
              message : text.value
            });
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });   
      }

    })();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It said very clearly that you are missing socket.io.js script. Just add it.

Comment: Yup. The html page has a reference to /socket.io/socket.io.js. For whatever reason, it's not deployed to heroku. As an experiment you might try loading it from a CDN.

Comment: i tried loading it from a CDN but still i got the same error again

Comment: any suggestions ? i really need help , i tried so many attempts and failed i cant deploy it on heroku at all

Comment: You need to put socket.io script in head tag.

Comment: i put the script in the head tag but still got the same 404 not found error :S

Comment: Anyone found a solution? I'm still having trouble with this